# Zeropad a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, zero-pad

I'm having a signal y of 52989 x 2 values. What I want to do is zero pad it until I get like signal y_mp3 66379 x 2.
Here a sample of my code:

```
P = 13750
y= [zeros(1,P),w];
```

I constantly receive the error: dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
I tried to switch the 1 and P or the 2 arguments but stil no good.
Can someone clarify my error?

EDIT:
I tried following suggestion but still the same:

```
P = length(y)-length(y_mp3);
y_mp3_p = y_mp3;
padsize = P / 2;
padarray(y_mp3_p, [padsize 0]);
```

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You can use MATLAB `padarray()` function. The code below may work:

```
padsize = p / 2;
padarray(w, [padsize 0]);
```

or,

```
p = 13750;
padarray(w, [p 0],'pre');
```

Comment: `padarray` is the solution, +1.

Comment: Btw, use size() function instead of using lenght() because length() function may cause some problem for matrix. Your naming in the code is a little confusing. I have revised your code line by line: Line1 -> P = size(y_mp3, 1)-size(y, 1); Line2 -> padsize = P / 2; Line3 -> y_p = padarray(y, [padsize 0]);

Comment: I reversed the first line otherwise P would be negative. Now it seems that I zero padded but way too much :) I get 80489x2 instead of 66739x2.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mehmet I finally found it!
It should be:

```
P = size(y,1) - size(y_mp3,1);
padsize = P/2 ;
y_p = padarray(y_mp3, [padsize 0],'sym');
```

Comment: Are you sure about that code above. You asked zeropad but does this code take symmetrics of the y signal matrix? Anyway, if you say so, I am glad to work..